# Who can crack this twitter regexp?

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I would like to grab all the hashtags using PHP from http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23eu-jele%C4%A1%C4%A1i

The hashtags are in the content, title nodes within the RSS feed.  They are prefixed with #

The problem I am having is with non-English letters (outside of the range a-zA-Z).

If you look at the RSS feed and then view the html source my struggle might be clearer.

```
    <title>And more: #eu-jele&#289;&#289;i #eu-kiest #ue-wybiera #eu-eleger #ue-alege #eu-vyvolenej #eu-izvoli #eu-elegir #eu-v&#228;lja #eu-elect</title>
```

Do I need to do some something with the title node before I find my rexexp matches.

My ultimate aim is to replace the hashtag with the twitter search url e.g. http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23eu-jele%C4%A1%C4%A1i

Here is some sample code to help you along.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<body>
<?php 
$title="And more: #eu-jele&#289;&#289;i #eu-kiest #ue-wybiera #eu-eleger #ue-alege #eu-vyvolenej #eu-izvoli #eu-elegir #eu-v&#228;lja #eu-elect";

// this is the regexp that hashtags.org use (http://twitter.pbwiki.com/Hashtags)
$r = preg_replace("/(?:(?:^#|[\s\(\[]#(?!\d\s))(\w+(?:[_\-\.\+\/]\w+)*)+)/"," <a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23\1\">\1</a> ", $title);
echo "<p>$r</p>";

$r = preg_replace("/(#.+?)(?:(\s|$))/"," <a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\1\">\1</a> ", $title);
echo "<p>$r</p>";

// This is my desired end result
echo "<p><a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23eu-jeleġġi\">#eu-jeleġġi</a></p>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any advice or solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Or just

```
(#\S+)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need the exact regular expression Twitter uses to render hashtags, Twitter provides it, along with the patterns for link, mentions, etc., in this [open source library](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/02/introducing-open-source-twitter-text.html).

### Hashtag Match Pattern

```
(^|[^0-9A-Z&/]+)(#|\uFF03)([0-9A-Z_]*[A-Z_]+[a-z0-9_\\u00c0-\\u00d6\\u00d8-\\u00f6\\u00f8-\\u00ff]*)
```

The above pattern can be pieced together from [this](https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-java/blob/master/src/com/twitter/Regex.java) java file. Validation tests for this pattern are located in [this file](https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-conformance/blob/master/autolink.yml) around line 115.

Answer (score 1):

Grab a '#' plus all characters until you hit a whitespace character:

```
(#.+?)(?:\s)
```

Or a little more flexible (allows end of string) :

```
(#.+?)(?:(\s|$))
```

Answer (score 1):

heres what i would use :)

```
(?<![^\s#])(#[^\s#]+)(?=(\s|$))
```

example matching on this string

**#test** #test#test **#test-test** test#test

hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a regexp?  Remove anything that's not preceded by a hash, then explode by hash.  Regexp seems unnecessarily complicated and ill-suited to the problem.

Perhaps you can explain further why this needs to be done in a regexp?

Comment: Adam this is a fair comment.  I have updated my original post with a little more detailed requirement.