# Scrape HTML for twitter usernames

Tags: c#, regex, twitter

I need a regex that match Twitter usernames.

So I want to scrape HTML of the page to get all valid Twitter usernames.
So the emails should not be returned, and also invalid usernames as I know that there are some some characters not permitted in Twitter username.

Bonus if a C# example is provided.

EDITED:

What I have until now is:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)/i");
string html = GetPageHtml(uri);
Match match = regex.Match(html);
```

I checked this but it is not working fine. Also I got info that twitter library has function for this but I cannot find it.

I am not really familiar with Regex

Comment: Have you tried anything? We're not here for free service giveways. I would probably utilize the [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), parsing out the text content and match against that data instead of the scraped HTML content.

Comment: Have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5768768/1400768 According to the author, it's from Twitter's library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do:

```
/[^\w]@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})(?:\b)(?![\;\:\-\.\[\]\*\?\!\$\^\+\/\#\"\'\=\(\)\&\@á-ź{-º])/igm
```

Here's a test: http://regexr.com/3bss5

I tested it in Javascript, but I believe you won't have any issue making it work in C#

Comment: This regex matches spaces before and after matched word. Can you please fix it so it doesn't match those spaces

Comment: It has a capture group, just use the first one and it will only have the username.

Comment: There is one more issue. If string is: "Something '@username' '@username2', it will return just @username. It doesn't return username if it is right after some other username. The single quotes are just because stackoverflow tagging users

Comment: Ok, let me try to fix it. I'll get back at you.

Comment: ok thank you. To be more clear the problem is when there is just one space between the usernames. This is probably because of the thing from my first comment

Comment: Test this one: http://regexr.com/3bss5 you're making me sweat :P

Comment: Heheh Thank you very much :)